# \ohm does'n show while using user font

Tags: fontspec, siunitx, unicode-math, math-fonts

I want to use Source Serif Pro as mainfont and XITS Math as mathfont. But     `\setmainfont{Source Serif Pro}` makes `\SI{100}{\ohm}` not working.

[image]

if remove `\setmainfont{Source Serif Pro}`, it looks pretty good, but the question is, I need the font as main foot

[image]

How to fix it? I want to use mathfont for all SI-Unit

Thank you all in Advance!

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage[detect-weight]{siunitx}
\usepackage{bm} 

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{Source Serif Pro}
\setmathfont[StylisticSet=1]{XITS Math}


\begin{document}
        \SI{100}{\ohm} \\
        $100 \Omega$ % Omega as ohm, not nice
\end{document}
```

Comment: From the manual of `amsbsy`: "Note: It is recommended nowadays to use the bm package, which
became available in 1997." Are you sure you need the `amsbsy` package? The note suggests that you should be fine using just `bm`.

Comment: @Skillmon thanks for the advice,  I will delete it.

Comment: Regarding the symbol, it seems like the font you're using doesn't have that symbol. You could either use another font that has one or borrow it from another font. I think there are questions on the network on how to use single symbols from another font.

Comment: @Skillmon, the mainfont `Source Serif Pro` doesn't have the symbol but mathfont has. How to use the mathfont for this unit-sysmbol

Comment: You might use `\sisetup{detect-mode=false,mode=math}` to make sure `siunitx` uses the math font everywhere.

Comment: @Skillmon but still not working in this case...

Comment: But it should in theory. Are you sure the math font covers the required symbol? (I'm not that good with fonts, maybe wait for someone more experienced than I am)

Comment: You could as well redefine the `\ohm` unit to print something you can control. As a fallback you could for example let it print an uppercase `\Omega` using something like `\DeclareSIUnit\ohm{\ensuremath{\Omega}}`.

Comment: Try removing `\usepackage{gensymb}` as well as `\usepackage{amssymb}`.

Comment: @RuixiZhang still not working, only remove `\setmainfont{Source Serif Pro}`, the question is, I need this font as main font..

Comment: Using your current MWE and compiling with LuaLaTeX I do get the correct output (before I was trying with XeLaTeX which threw an error).

Comment: In addition to @Skillmon, I just tested the new MWE using XeLaTeX with Source Serif Pro [from here](https://github.com/adobe-fonts/source-serif-pro/releases/tag/2.007R-ro/1.007R-it) and XITS Math [from here](https://github.com/khaledhosny/xits), and the output is correct: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgRvc.png.

Comment: @RuixiZhang crying, I still got the wrong ouput

Comment: I can only suggest to reinstall the newest version of Source Serif Pro via the [GitHub release page](https://github.com/adobe-fonts/source-serif-pro/releases/tag/2.007R-ro/1.007R-it). If you scroll down, one feature mentioned there was “double-map various glyphs (e.g. Greek capital letter Omega/Ohm)”. Maybe it was a bug but now fixed.

Comment: @RuixiZhang I have done, but still, `Missing character: There is no Ω in font Source Serif Pro/OT:script=latn;language=DFLT;!`

Comment: @ now solved, reinstalled the new OTF-Version, then worked, nice.

Comment: @RuixiZhang can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the newest Source Serif Pro (Roman fonts version 2.007 and Italic fonts version 1.007) found [here on GitHub](https://github.com/adobe-fonts/source-serif-pro/releases), and the newest XITS Math found [here on GitHub](https://github.com/khaledhosny/xits), your MWE produces the correct output. One of the new feature of Source Serif Pro states

> double-map various glyphs (e.g. Greek capital letter Omega/Ohm)

So probably this was a bug, but now fixed in the Source Serif Pro font family.

Since you are using XITS Math with `unicode-math`, you should *not* load `amssymb` (this package provides symbols based on Computer Modern). Also, `gensymb` is IMHO unnecessary.

```
% Compile with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[detect-weight]{siunitx}
\usepackage{bm}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Source Serif Pro}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[StylisticSet=1]{XITS Math}

\begin{document}
    \noindent \SI{100}{\ohm} \\
    $100 \Omega$ % Omega as ohm, not nice
\end{document}
```

[image: correct Omega]